# Why doesn't Internet Explorer 8 compatibility mode work?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

A client's page that was built for Internet Explorer 7 was tagged using the compatibility mode meta tag, so that it rendered correctly on Internet Explorer  8 as well. This **worked for a while**.

Recently, testing the page reveals some severe issues, that are resolved only once the 'compatibility mode' button at the top of the browser is pressed. The tag is correct and is correctly positioned in the document, and the source code hasn't changed. What could have happened?

This is the code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: may you send the metatag that you used inside code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today! The workaround is in *[Compatibility Mode doesn’t work in Internet Explorer 8.. Why?](http://starikovs.com/2010/03/12/compatibility-mode-doesnt-work-in-ie8/)*. It didn't work for me because the <meta> tag that turns on the Compatibility Mode was going after the <script> tag. The Compatibility Mode <meta> tag must go at the beginning of the <head> before any scripts or CSS styles.

Comment: yes, i forgot to close the question :) silly me, that was the problem with the page, someone added some stuff before the meta.